# Is using luajit vs lua C bindings actually faster?

Tags: c, lua

Is using the `LuaJIT` library better than using the lua C official library in terms of performance ?

From I have read (the only what was possible), the luajit's feature is only the FFI interface. But I have also read that `luajit` adds some optimizations to the standard `lua-c` API but could not find any information about this unfortunately.

I don't understand, does it impact the performance when used without its FFI interface? There is also no any information about how it compiles the code, during the `lua_loadfile` or anywhen else?

To be more concrete, I want to use lua via the C api and not the `luajit` FFI interface by making a shared library which lua script can use then.

Comment: Even without FFI, sometimes you can rewrite C library as Lua library, so that LuaJIT will run this Lua code a bit faster (about 5%?) than original C code (due to benefits of trace JIT compiler).

Comment: I have libzmq binding via C and FFI. Can checkout perfomance test https://github.com/zeromq/lzmq#performance or write your own. This 2 libs has same API and can be just drop in replace each other.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I still wanna know is `luajit` faster than `lua C` bindings for using it in the C code without producing shared libraries? I mean exactly the C API.

Comment: @moteus thank you for link to the `lzmq`. But I don't need the FFI at all, I need only `C API`: using lua from within the `C code` via `lua_pcall` and so on.

Comment: In my experience, FFI only allows you to call a function using C semantics.  In a hand crafted Lua binding, one can add "Lua-isms" and make a function more Lua friendly.  FWIW, I have a FFI for Lua that does not use LuaJIT.